# Single array JSON object will not print (Ionic 2)

Tags: angularjs, json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am pulling data from an API for recipes, I already have a list of recipes which works fine, however I am now calling for a single recipes details (**1 object**). My console log below is what the JSON looks like. Whatever I do I cannot get to display on the front end, please help where you can.

[image: JSON]

TypeScript

```
details: any;

loadDetails() {
  if (this.details) {
    return Promise.resolve(this.details);
  }

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.http.get('http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipe/Crustless-Ham-Savory-Bake-2005439?_app_id=//////&_app_key=/////')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.details = data;
        resolve(this.details);
      });
  });
}
```

HTML

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
            <h1>{{details.id}}</h1>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Pagename.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-details',
  templateUrl: 'details.html',
  providers: [ApiAuthentication]

})
export class DetailsPage {

  public api: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public apiAuthentication: ApiAuthentication) {
    this.loadRecipes();
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad DetailsPage');
  }

  loadRecipes(){
    this.apiAuthentication.loadDetails()
    .then(data => {
      this.api = data;
    });
  } 
}
```

Comment: I dont see description anywhere in the returned object. you need a key to access try details.id forst to see if id is printing

Comment: @AniruddhaDas Sorry I have now changed to ID (was messing with other values) I get an error of **Cannot read property 'id' of undefined**

Comment: @BA1995. It's a classic case of async value: your template tries to access `details.id` **before** `details` is actually defined (it is NOT assigned immediately since it is the result of an async cold). Try `{{details?.id}}` in your template.

Comment: Use the elvis operator (?) like this to avoid that error `<h1>{{details?.id}}</h1>`. That's because the promise is not yet resolved when trying to print the id.

Comment: @AngularFrance Thankyou for this, I now have lost the error in console. As you can tell I'm new to this, advice on moving forward?

Comment: [Read the doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#safe-navigation-operator)? :-)) I'm partly joking. They did a great job with the angular.io docs and all of the "guides" can be read as book chapters from start to finish. That said, Observables take a while to wrap your head around. They're a bit outside the scope of Angular itself but investing in understanding them thoroughly will make you a better developer. For this I'd recommend learnrxjs.io which has usage examples for all major RxJS operators and egghead.io which has nice RxJS video tutorials (some paid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to display

```
<h1>{{details.id}}</h1>
```

when you have in fact your object in `api`:

```
loadRecipes(){
  this.apiAuthentication.loadDetails()
    .then(data => {
      this.api = data; // you store it in api!
  });
```

so this should probably be cleared out by just changing your template a bit:

```
<h1>{{api.id}}</h1>
```

and perhaps add the safe navigation operator here as well. `{{api?.id}}`

Comment: Thats great! I didn't realise `?` can get you through the error

Comment: The safe navigation operator guards null values, you can read more here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator You'll get used to using this A LOT with Angular since we are constantly dealing with async :)

Answer (score 0):

You are actually trying many thing and can be done with one of the tings.

you are using both promise and observable and you can avoid one of them. I would say use observable as it comes by default.

```
loadDetails() {
  if (this.details) {
    return null;
  }

  this.http.get('http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipe/Crustless-Ham-Savory-Bake-2005439?_app_id=//////&_app_key=/////')
      //.map(res => res.json())  // you don't need this
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);  // make sure the data is the object you are expecting and have the id property
        this.details = data; // not necessary if you will use async pipe
      });
  });
}
```

here details.id should be available.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question to include the more code pulling that function, I do also need the `.map(res => res.json())` to convert the json into an object